# solr-thumbnail - some jpegs are not processed

Tags: python, django

I got a few pictures which I upload from django admin using solr.thumbnail.ImageField and it works perfectly - image is uploaded to media folder, thumbnails are created in cache subdir and proper entries in thumbnail_kvstore are created.

I got some images, which do not work though - they are uploaded to media folder, but no cache entries and no thumbnails are created. No errors or anything raised.

```
Django==1.8
Pillow==3.0.0
sorl-thumbnail==12.3
```

This picture I obtained from bigger one and resizing down, but same behaviour applies to original picture also.
What should I look into to make those pictures work?

[image: E.g. not working image]

Comment: damn, this looks so good! yummy..

Comment: is there anything in common with the pictures that don't work? Is it anything to do with filesize?

Comment: @Sayse: I willl double check tomorrow, but all images were made by the same photographer, all of them are big like 10 MB, which I sized down. For those not affected it doesn't matter if I upload 10 MB picture or 0,5 MB, they work. For those affected - neither of them work. I thought it's related to image tags maybe..

Comment: @doniyor: I think solr-thumbnail eats my burgers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use Pillow==2.9.3 or wait for 3.1.0. [More info](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/pull/1492).

Comment: Pillow 3.1.0 was released on 4th January 2016, please upgrade like: `pip install -U pillow`